# Invoking C# Delegate Method when delegate is passed as Generic Argument

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I'm having trouble preventing duplicate code.

Currently I have these methods:

```
protected delegate bool CallbackDelegate<T>(T param, out string result);
protected delegate bool CallbackDelegate<T, U>(T param1, U param2, out string result);

protected bool ClientCtrlCallback<T>(T param, CallbackDelegate<T> callbackMethod)
{...}
protected bool ClientCtrlCallback<T,U>(T param1, U param2, CallbackDelegate<T,U> callbackMethod)
{...}
```

Both ClientCtrlCallback methods have equal code (checking validity of communication channels, try-catch block, obtaining lock, etc) built around the call to the CallbackDelegate method.

I've been trying to merge these ClientCtrl methods, but didn't succeed because the delegate constraint is not allowed. This is as far as I got: (unnecessary code removed for clarity)

```
protected delegate bool CallbackDelegate1<T>(T param, out string result);
protected delegate bool CallbackDelegate2<T, U>(T param1, U param2, out string result);
protected const string METHOD_MY_DELEGATE1 = "CallbackDelegate1";
protected const string METHOD_MY_DELEGATE2 = "CallbackDelegate2";
protected interface ParameterSet { };
protected class OneParameter<T>: ParameterSet { public T p1; };
protected class TwoParameters<T,U> : ParameterSet { public T p1; public U p2; };

protected bool ClientCtrlCallback<D,T,U>(ParameterSet parameterset, D callbackMethod, string successLog = null) // where MyDelegate : delegate  //not allowed
{
  // delegate constrained is not allowed, so check it here
  if (!typeof(D).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Delegate)))
    return false;

  // check name of method (this works)
  string methodName = (callbackMethod as Delegate).Method.Name;

  // Call the delegate // doesn't work.
  string result;
  switch (methodName)
  {
    case METHOD_MY_DELEGATE1:
      // doesnt work
      //(callbackMethod as Delegate)((parameterset as OneParameter<T>).p1, out result);
      break;

    case METHOD_MY_DELEGATE2:
      // doesnt work
      //(callbackMethod as Delegate)((parameterset as TwoParameters<T, U>).p1, (parameterset as TwoParameters<T, U>).p2, out result); // doesnt work
      break;
  }
  return true;
}
```

It starts getting ugly with the parameter classes. It gets worse with the switch comparing the delegates' names (I also don't like having to each give them a different name). And then there's total trouble when I want to call the Delegate's method: compile time error `Method name expected`

I don't understand why I can get the method name from the Delegate, but not invoke the Delegate's method. Am I missing something big?

Comment: Maybe replace the entire thing with classes, interfaces, virtual methods and all that jazz?

Comment: Don't do this. If there's excess duplicated code in the two methods then abstract away the duplicated code into helper methods. But don't change the signatures of your two methods and then try to enforce the type system at runtime. More generally: people spend too much time worrying about small duplications. They are expensive to deduplicate, as you are discovering, and that effort could be better spent on writing tests, looking for bugs, designing the next version, and so on.

Comment: Try use Action<> ?

Comment: @lindexi He couldn't with the signature's he's using.

Comment: @Eric, you may be right that I've gone a bit too far. I thought about indeed moving the checks to a helper class, but I tried harder in generalizing because it's not possible for all of them.
That being said, my only real question is - why can't I invoke the method, even though I can get its name from the delegate. I bumped into it, now I want to find out :) Is it a language limitation? Is that the reason why the delegate constrain is not allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**
Can't you just have:

```
protected delegate bool CallbackDelegate<TParameterSet>(TParameterSet param, out string result)
    where TParameterSet : ParameterSet;
```

Then (doesn't seem that useful now, depending on the rest of your code):

```
protected bool ClientCtrlCallback<TParameterSet>(TParameterSet parameterset, CallbackDelegate<TParameterSet> callbackMethod, string successLog = null)
    where TParameterSet : ParameterSet
{
    string result;
    return callbackMethod(parameterset, out result);
}
```

And finally your callback methods:

```
bool CallbackMethodOneParameter<T>(OneParameter<T> parameter, out string result)
{
    // Do your stuff with parameter.p1;
    // set result
    // return success or fail
}

bool CallbackMethodTwoParameters<T, U>(TwoParameters<T, U> parameters, out string result)
{
    // Do your stuff with parameters.p1 and parameters.p2;
    // set result
    // return success or fail
}
```

**NO LONGER APPLY**
*I'm also wondering if you really need to use generics here. Your callback methods might already know which types your ParameterSet contains.

Because, with this generics, if you need another argument, you will have to change everywhere this signature. And it can become painful.*

---

In your code, to call your delegate, you can do that:

```
var parameters = new object[] { (parameterset as OneParameter<T>).p1, null };
var success = (callbackMethod as Delegate).DynamicInvoke(parameters);
result = parameters[1];
```

Comment: this is indeed possible, but let's assume the callback methods cannot be changed

Comment: You will need wrapper methods, but I quite don't like the idea. (or you will need a totally different solution)

Comment: @Brecht, My edit might interest you and I also answered how to call your delegate ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it the responsibility of this method to accept parameters that will be passed into the callback in the first place.  Don't pass in *any* parameters.  If the caller has a value that they want to use within the callback then can use a closure to close over that variable.

Not only is it extremely hard for this object to accept an arbitrary number of parameters and pass them into the callback (and impossible to fully generalize in a type safe manner) and also trivially easy for the caller to solve this problem in an entirely general case and fully type safe manner, but that information is logically a private implementation detail of the caller, and isn't information that this method has any reason to know about in the first place.